# GetHashCode() и Equals() в Hashtable

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется следующий код:

```
public class Fish
    {
        private readonly string name;

        public Fish(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var otherFish = obj as Fish;

            if (otherFish == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        return otherFish.name == name;
    }
}

class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var duplicates = new Hashtable();

            var key1 = new Fish("Herring");
            var key2 = new Fish("Herring");
            var key3 = new Fish("Herring2");

            duplicates[key1] = "Hello";
            duplicates[key2] = "Hello2";
            duplicates[key3] = "Hello3";

            Console.WriteLine(duplicates.Count);

            // Delay.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

При вызове строк
`duplicates[key1] = "Hello"` и `duplicates[key3] = "Hello3"` вызывается только метод GetHashCode(), а при вызове `duplicates[key2] = "Hello3"`, вызывается метод Equals(). Как компилятор определил когда нужно вызывать метод Equals() и когда в этом нет потребности?

Comment: Это определил не компилятор, а реализация хеш таблицы. Вы же в duplicates[key2] используете ключ с именем `"Herring"` который уже добавили строчкой выше - вот у них хеш коды и совпали, потому и Equals вызвался

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если упростить, то хеш-таблица работает так:

- Вызывается `GetHashCode()` для ключа
- Если есть совпадения с хеш-кодом, который уже находится в таблице, вызывается метод `Equals()`. То, что хеш-коды совпали, еще не значит, что `Equals()` вернет `true`
- Если объекты равны, то перезаписывается запись в таблице, если не равны, будет добавлена новая

`duplicates[key2] = "Hello2";` на этой строчке совпал хеш-код, но хеш-таблица должна проверить, равен ли ключ уже существующему в таблице, поэтому вызывается `Equals()`

На практике берется `GetHashCode() % table_length`, где `table_length` размер внутренней таблицы.

Comment: На практике, оригинальная хеш-таблица (Hashtable), использует метод открытой адресации для разрешения коллизий и будет перебирать бакеты пока не встретит пустой. В случае ТС, именно там и будет вызван Equals – https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/hashtable.cs,957

Comment: @АртёмОконечникову у вас ссылка веден не на "встретит пустой" а на "встретит занятый, или опустошенный; с тем же ключом". в случае топикастера - находится занятый бакет.